# What is the point of specifying the size of an array in a parameter declaration?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = {1,2};

void test(int in[3]){
  //
}
 
int main() {
 test(a); 
 return 0;
}
```

In the above code `int in[3]` is the same as `int *in`. The number `3` doesn't really do anything and it's not even the correct size, but even so the compiler doesn't complain. So is there a reason this syntax is accepted in C or I'm missing a functionality?

Comment: In some circumstances, the compiler may make optimization decisions based on the declared size of the array. It can assume the array is at least that big. Calling the function with an array that's too small invokes undefined behaviour. The compiler is neither obliged to tell you when you invoke undefined behaviour, nor to use the size hint. In the more general case, where you have `void test(int size, int in[size]);`, there is value in providing the size. The function now knows how big the array is. Whether the compiler exploits that information is a QoI (quality of implementation) issue.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176512/forcing-an-array-size-in-a-function-parameter-in-c-when-passing-an-array

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think it should be `void test(int size, int* in)` instead of `void test(int size, int in[size])`. As far as I know, the size of an array allocated from stack must have a fixed size known during compilation.

Comment: At no time during the current millennium has that been a requirement of the current C standard, @AkibAzmain.  C99 introduced variable-length arrays; C11 made them optional (a retrograde step IMO, but I was not privy to the reasons why that change was made).  You need to move beyond the rules of the 30-year old C90 standard and become cognizant of the rules for modern C.

Comment: Note C11 [§6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes) ¶7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7): _A declaration of a parameter as ''array of type'' shall be adjusted to ''qualified pointer to type'', where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation._ […continued…]

Comment: […continuation…] _If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression._. (In my original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64905476/what-is-the-point-of-passing-the-size-of-an-array-in-c#comment114752848_64905476), I'd forgotten about the keyword `static` being necessary to guarantee/require at least N elements in the array.  Mea culpa.)

Answer (score 5):

When an array parameter declaration contains a constant size, the only purpose it can serve is as documentation for readers, by indicating to them what size array the function expects. For a constant expression `n`, the compiler converts an array declaration such as `int in[n]` to `int *in`, after which there is no difference to the compiler and so nothing is affected by the value of `n`.

Originally in C, function parameters were specified by a list of declarations after the initial function declaration, such as:

```
int f(a, b, c)
int a;
float b;
int c[3];
{
    … function body
}
```

I conjecture that array sizes were permitted in these declarations simply because they used the same grammar as other declarations. It would have been harder to write compiler code and documentation that excluded the sizes than to simply allow them to occur but to ignore them. When declaring paramter types inside function prototypes (`int f(int a, float b, int c[3])`) was introduced, I conjecture the same reasoning applied.

However:

- If the declaration contains `static`, as in `int in[static n]`, then, when the function is called, the corresponding argument must point to at least `n` elements, per C 2018 6.7.6.3 7. Compilers may use this for optimization.
- If the array size is not a constant, it may be evaluated by the compiler when the function is called. For example, if the function declaration is `void test(int in[printf("Hi")])`, then both GCC 10.2 and Apple Clang 11.0 print “Hi” when the function is called. (However, it is not clear to me the C standard requires this evaluation.)
- This adjustment occurs only for the actual array parameter, not arrays within it. For example, in the parameter declaration `int x[3][4]`, the type of `x` is adjusted to be `int (*)[4]`. The 4 remains a part of the size and has effects on pointer arithmetic with `x`.
- When a parameter is declared as an array, the element type must be complete. In contrast, a parameter declared as a pointer need not point to a complete type. For example, `struct foo x[3]` yields a diagnostic message if `struct foo` has not been fully defined, but `struct foo *x` does not.

Comment: I am inclined to guess that the original reason was so that it was acceptable to exactly match the declared type of array objects with the declared types of function parameters with which they are associated.  Maybe I'll check whether K&R speaks to that when I am near my copy.  That would be more or less the same as the leading remarks of this answer.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I checked places where the original K&R mentions formal parameters, per the index, and did not see anything.

Answer (score 2):

If we specify the size of the array in the function definition, it can be used for checking errors using static analysis tool. I used `cppcheck` tool for the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(int in[3])
{
  in[3] = 4;
}
```

The output is:

```
Cppcheck 2.2
[test.cpp:4]: (error) Array 'in[3]' accessed at index 3, which is out of bounds.
Done!
```

But, if you donot give any size, you will not get any error from `cppcheck` .

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(int in[])
{
   in[3] = 4;
}
```

The output is :

```
Cppcheck 2.2
Done!
```

But , in general, there is no need to specify the size of the array, in function definition. We cannot find the size of array inside another function, using `sizeof` operator, because only value of the pointer is copied. Hence, input  of `sizeof` operator will be of type `int*` and not of type `int[]` (inside the function `test()`). So, the value of the size of array does not effect the code.  See the code below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};

void test(int in[8]) // Same as void test(int *arr)
{
    unsigned int n = sizeof(in) / sizeof(in[0]); // sizeof(int*)/sizeof(int)
    printf("Array size inside test() is %d\n", n);
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);  //sizeof(int[])/sizeof(int)
    printf("Array size inside main() is %d\n", n);
    test(a);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Array size inside main() is 8
Array size inside test() is 2
```

So, we need to pass the size of an array with an another variable.

Comment: Your output is for 64-bit computers, on 32-bit it will change.

Comment: In spite of OP’s title, they are asking what is the point of specifying the array dimension in the parameter declaration, not what the point of passing the size as a parameter/argument is. This answer does not speak to that question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil   There is not need to pass the size of array to the function. It does not matter, even if you pass it. That's what I am trying to tell.

Comment: "What is the point of ...?"  means, why we are doing it (I think) . My answer : No need to do it.

Comment: Then you should change the phrasing of the first sentence. The declaration does not occur “while passing it to a function.” The first sentence could say “There is no need to specify the size of the array in a parameter declaration.”

Comment: That there is no need to specify the size is exactly the OP's point.  The question is *because* there's no need to specify the size, why does the language allow it to be specified at all?

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Thank you for pointing my mistake. I modified it. Please see it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger  I modified my answer, Please see it. Thank you for pointing my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In C, there is no difference between a pointer to one structure and a pointer to an array of the same data structure. To get the start address of the next you simply increment the pointer with the size of the data and since it is impossible to determine the size from only the pointer itself you must supply this as a programmer.

Lets try to modify the program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int in[3]){
  printf("%d %d,%d,%d\n",in[0],in[1],in[2],in[3]); // !Sic bug intentional 
}
int main() {
 int a[] = {1,2};
 int b[] = {3,4};
 test(a); 
 test(b); 
 return 0;
}
```

And run it:

```
$ gcc pointer_size.c  -o a.out  && ./a.out 

1 2,3,4
3 4,-1420617472,-1719256057
```

In this case the arrays are placed back to back to each other, so reading at index 2 and 3 from a will yield the data from b and when we read too much from b whatever present on those  addresses will be read.

This is a very common source for security vulnerabilities even to this date.

Comment: It's possible to determine size, just try to access elements in array (e.g `arr[0]; are[1]; ...`). When you go out of range, you'll get a segmentation fault and the number of successful attempts is the size of array.

Comment: @AkibAzmain: you are not guaranteed a segfault when you access out of the bounds of an array.  You're only guaranteed undefined behaviour, which means anything can happen.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler On most operating systems this will happen (except systems like embedded devices).

Comment: @AkibAzmain: no.  It is more likely that there is another data structure after the array that you are abusing, and the out of bounds access will read data that is not part of the array, or write to data that is not part of the array.  If it is the very last variable in the data section, then you may get a crash, and if the array index gets big enough, you will eventually get a crash, but accessing a few elements outside of the bounds of an array will not usually cause a crash because of the out of bounds access — but changed data may cause a crash, or invalid data may give erroneous results.

Comment: In spite of OP’s title, they are asking what is the point of specifying the array dimension in the parameter declaration, not what the point of passing the size as a parameter/argument is. This answer does not speak to that question.

Comment: Fair point, the wording was "passing" when I wrote this answer before your edit of the question. Anyway, I will just leave it here maybe it  is useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

As far as the C language and compiler cares, it doesn't matter if you specify the size since the array gets adjusted to a pointer to the first element anyway.

However, stating the size can improve the ability for static analysis by external tools other than the compiler. For example, a static analyser can easily tell that this is an array out-of-bounds bug:

```
void test(int in[3]){
  in[3] = 0;
}
```

But it has no idea if this is a bug:

```
void test(int* in){
  in[3] = 0;
}
```

---

Related to this, the non-existent type safety between different array sizes can actually be solved by using a trick - pass arrays by pointer instead. Because a pointer to an array does not decay and is picky about getting handed the right size. Example:

```
void test(int (*in)[3]){
  int* ptr = *in;
  ptr[3] = 0;
}

int foo[10];
test(&foo);  // compiler error

int bar[3];
test(&bar);  // ok
```

However, this trick makes the code a bit harder to read and understand.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I checked the code with `cppcheck` static analyser. It gave me `out of bounds` error.